# Relative Layout and text over images

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom component, that has an `ImageView`, and a Text. My problem is, if I set the text `centerHorizontal=true` in the layout, the text centers ok, but if the text is too long it overlaps on the image view. If I set `layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageviewid"`, the text is not overlapped, but the text looks too close to the image view. I would like my text be centered, but without overlapping the `ImageView.`

I checked [this](http://layout_toRightOf=%22@+id/imagecolor%22), that is the solution I tried, but it does not fit to me.

The Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imagecolor"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textcolor"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagecolor"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what you want to achieve

Comment: can you please show us a picture what you wanted to do

Comment: I need the text centered, but without overlapping the ImageView in the left. Currently, if the text is too long, it overlaps. If I set torightof, it does not overlaps, but if text is too short, it appears too close to the ImageView...

Comment: A better idea is to set the image **inside** the TextView, as a **compound drawable** - This also reduces the View count, for better performances.

Comment: I can't do that, Frank. I need the ImageView and the TextView, side by side.

Comment: Which is what you get by using `drawableLeft="yourImage"`, in xml. You can also set it in Java.

Comment: If you really want to keep your **unoptimized** layout, then please swap the Space and the TextView and set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for the TextView. Also, **px** is **evil**. Please, use **dp**, instead.

Comment: I will explain further...this is going to be some kind of legend in a calendar, in which I painted some colors in certain dates. So, is kind of "this color means this thing" in the calendar. So, there are going to be more than one. If I use drawable:left, the drawable will look misaligned relative the others.

Comment: Yeah, the px is a mistake. Should be dp.

Comment: You can have **4** compound drawables in a single TextView. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Answer (score 2):

You can give the margin from the left to your text view , it would always make distance with left image view.

android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
....
.....

Comment: Yes, but how could I know the distance I need for margin? If text is short, I don't need any margin. If it is long, I would need it...but how much? I don't think it is viable.

Comment: Give the margin of 5 dp everytime, i don't think that it would create any issue in look wise even your textview and imageview would always be separate. Anyway, Could you put snapshot of your screen what currently you are showing and what you want, that would be great to detect the actual requirement.

Comment: Im almost out of office now...will do later. but I am starting to consider using a TableLayout instead of RelativeLayout...

Comment: Margins will also help eliminating the Space, reducing the View count, therefore increasing the performances.

Comment: @Fustigador, you can also use Linear Layout instead of relative layout and can give the weight to the child and it would solve the problem.